# PHP why is 0=='all' true?

Tags: php

I am reading the PHP documentation for boolean.

One of the comments says 0=='all' is true.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#86809

I want to know how it becomes true.

The documentation says all non-empty strings are true except '0'.

So 'all' is true
and
0 is false.

`false == true` should be false.

But:

```
if(0=='all'){
    echo 'hello';
}else{
   echo 'how are you ';
}
```

prints 'hello'.

Comment: Type inference is used, causing the expression to compare false with false.

Answer (score 9):

In PHP, operators == and != do not compare the type. Therefore PHP automatically converts 'all' to an integer which is 0.

```
echo intval('all');
```

You can use === operator to check type:

```
if(0 === 'all'){
    echo 'hello';
}else{
   echo 'how are you ';
}
```

See the [Loose comparisons](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) table.

Answer (score 4):

As you have as left operand an integer, php tries to cast the second one to integer. So as integer representation of a string is zero, then you have a `true` back.
If you switch operators you obtain the same result.

As Bhumi says, if you need this kind of comparison, use `===`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a string as condition in a IF steatment it is checked to be not empty or '0', but if you compare it with an integer (==, <, >, ...) it is converted to 0 int value.

```
if('all')
    echo 'this happens!';
if('all'>0 || 'all'<0)
    echo 'this never happens!';
```